# Как сделать гиперссылку на другой лист в Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Tags: laravel

Laravel version: 5.8
Package version: 2.1

Как сделать гиперссылку на другой лист?
Я знаю, как сделать обычную гиперссылку.

```
$sheet->getCell('A1')->getHyperlink()->setUrl('link');
$sheet->getCell('A1')->getHyperlink()->setTooltip('link_text');
```

Например, у меня есть два листа

```
$excel->sheet('Лист 1', function ($sheet) {
  //Как тут указать ссылку на лист 2?
  $sheet->fromArray($ct->prod);
  $sheet->getCell('A1')->getHyperlink()->setUrl('link_text');
});
$excel->sheet('Лист 2', function ($sheet) {

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен благодаря поддержке 'Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel'

[Статья](http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2010/04/11/phpexcel-how-to-link-to-another-worksheet/)

Решение:

```
$sheet->getCell('A1')->getHyperlink()->setUrl("sheet://'Лист 2'!A1");
```